# PHP- Combine child element of an array into an array

Tags: php, arrays

i had an array of data like this

```
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["cate_title"]=>
        string(30) "Printer Line - Round With Date"
        ["attr_id"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["attr"]=>
        string(6) "asdasd"
        ["option"]=>
        string(6) "asdasd"
        ["data_name"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["cate_title"]=>
        string(1) "w"
        ["attr_id"]=>
        string(2) "14"
        ["attr"]=>
        string(4) "asda"
        ["option"]=>
        string(5) "sdasd"
        ["data_name"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
      [2]=>
      array(5) {
        ["cate_title"]=>
        string(1) "w"
        ["attr_id"]=>
        string(2) "13"
        ["attr"]=>
        string(3) "aaa"
        ["option"]=>
        string(8) "checkbox"
        ["data_name"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(3) "bbb"
        }
      }
    }
```

i want to combine 2 elenment that has the same `cate_title = w` into 1 array like this

```html
<pre>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["cate_title"]=>
    string(30) "Printer Line - Round With Date"
    ["attr_id"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["attr"]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
    ["option"]=>
    string(6) "asdasd"
    ["data_name"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>  
  array(2) {
    ["cate_title"]=>string(1) "w"  

      ["data-child"]=>array(2){
        [0]=>array {

        ["attr_id"]=>string(2) "14"

        ["attr"]=>string(4) "asda"

        ["option"]=>string(5) "sdasd"

        ["data_name"]=> array(0) {    }

        }
        [1]=>array {

        ["attr_id"]=>string(2) "13"

        ["attr"]=>string(4) "aaa"

        ["option"]=>string(5) "checkbox"

        ["data_name"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(3) "bbb"

            }    
        }

    }

  }

</pre>
```

please help me, i've searched everywhere but still no answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution

```
<?php
    foreach($arr as $v){
        $newArr[$v["cate_title"]][] = $v;
    }
    var_dump(array_values($newArr));
?>
```

Comment: simple and effective , thank you !